# MySQL will not accept 0 as value

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I've recently upgraded a server to MySQL 5.7, and I have noticed that any query which attempts to insert 0 as number (ie, without quotation marks to make it a string) throws a syntax error.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO
    users_transactions
SET 
    `discount_percent` = 0,
    `total_cost` = 20.00;
```

Inserting the float 20.00 is fine, but 0 results in an 'unexpected token near ,' as if 0 was not a number.

This is legacy code, some of which has been running for 10 years or more. What has changed, and why would 0 be treated different from another number?

Searching for references to this behaviour haven't produced any results. It's easy enough to edit the query to read `discount_percent` = '0', but I'd like to understand why.

**UPDATE:**

Extra piece of information - I have seen this behaviour on multiple INT fields, not just this one.

Output of Describe
[image]

Schema: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tsZLhMLkGaCVQLNJq3KKZ/0

Comment: Can you show us the table?

Comment: Is that the right syntax for `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes it is. Didn't know that. Can you try the value `0.0`?

Comment: What does `DESCRIBE TABLE` say?

Comment: I have never seen `INSERT INTO` used with `SET`

Comment: Insert Command should be like this - `INSERT INTO users_transactions (discount_percent, total_cost)
VALUES (0,20.00);`

Comment: @Parth Patel Why? That's just one of three ways of doing it. And in any case, that wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: I have uploaded an image of the output of DESCRIBE command.

Comment: Can you please create a sample of your database schema here https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: I tested your query on 5.7.20 but I don't get an error for "unexpected token." I get an error "Field 'book_ids_purchased' doesn't have a default value" which is expected because 5.7 sets strict mode by default.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Yeah, that's a separate issue which I have resolved. But that's weird that you don't get an error. Or rather - it's weird that I do.

Comment: @hackerman Is this what you mean? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tsZLhMLkGaCVQLNJq3KKZ/0

Comment: @clinomaniac It's an smallint field so it won't accept floats or decimals.

Comment: @clinomaniac, The syntax is not standard SQL, but MySQL supports it as an extension to standard syntax. It is similar to UPDATE syntax. It helps make it clear which columns go with which values. But it doesn't support inserting multiple rows of data per statement.